# Symfony 1.4 routing issues only when using index.php and mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, symfony1, routes

The most succinct way of summarizing the problem at hand:

- Development is over, and everything was run against frontend_dev.php during development and testing

  This means that all URLs were: **server.com/frontend_dev.php/module/action/parm**
- Moving to production means switching environments, and thusly using index.php instead
  **server.com/index.php/module/action/parm**
- Part of moving to production is using mod_rewrite under Apache2 to make the “index.php” part of the URL vanish, but still be functioning
  **server.com/module/action/parm**  is still routed against index.php
- The URLs are indeed appearing w/o the index.php part, but symfony routing is now complaining:
  ie, server.com/goals   which routes to goals/index
  --  perfectly fine using frontend_dev.php or index.php as an explicit controller
  **server.com/index.php/goals**
  -- using no explicit controller (via rewrite):
  **[Tue Dec 14 12:59:51 2010] [error] [client 75.16.181.113] Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/goals/" (/)**

I have verified the rewrite is indeed routing to index.php by changing the rewrite to something that doesn’t exist:
**[Tue Dec 14 13:05:43 2010] [error] [client 75.16.181.113] script '/opt/www/projects/adam/web/index2.php' not found or unable to stat**

I have tried rerouting to frontend_dev.php, but only am provided with more debug information from symfony, none of which is helpful:

> 404 | Not Found | sfError404Exception  Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/goals/" (/).
>   stack trace
>   1. at () in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/controller/sfFrontWebController.class.php line 44 ...
>   2. at sfFrontWebController->dispatch() in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/util/sfContext.class.php line 170 ...
>   3. at sfContext->dispatch() in SF_ROOT_DIR/web/frontend_dev.php line 13 ...

I have tried the using the RewriteBase option in .htaccess, but that does not help any, nor changing the true/false in the configuration line of the controllers

I hope this provides enough to understand why we’re confused, and able to direct us to a resolution.

Following is the current .htaccess  and index/frontend configuration lines

Index.php:

> $configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', false);

Frontend_dev.php:

> $configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'dev', true);

.htaccess:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
>    # getting no_script_name to work
>    #RewriteBase /
>
> # we skip all files with .something
>    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ..+$
>    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.html$
>    #RewriteRule .* - [L]
>
> # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
>    RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
>    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
>    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
>    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

Comment: It seems strange that symfony complains about route not found when the request is being rewritten correctly - Have you tried dumping the route configuration directly to your browser via index.php? And clearing the cache manually, maybe? Also, try rewriting to your index2.php and have it print the query.

Comment: Could you post your routing.yml ?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and setting 'AllowOverride' to ALL for Symfony's WEB folder in Virtual Host's config sorted out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Maybe you're confusing the "index" route with "index.php"?

These URLs should theoretically all work.

```
server.com/frontend_dev.php/goals/index  
server.com/index.php/goals/index  
server.com/goals/index  
server.com/goals
```

I can't remember if the trailing slash, like `server.com/goals/`, works or not.  There's a gotcha there.